# FATAL EXCEPTION onItemSelected

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, fatal-error, onitemselectedlistener

My app sends USSD requests. It has an activity from where a fragment is launched which has buttons that launch AlertDialog and USSD requests are sent onItemSelected. Now the force close when I try to send the request and the log show the above error.

Log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.esqmo.apps.mosungiplus, PID: 14315
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel :*1050*100# }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1879)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1546)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4298)
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatJB.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompatJB.java:30)
at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:146)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:932)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:1047)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:940)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:929)
at com.esqmo.apps.mosungiplus.fragments.AfricellNetFragment.onItemSelected(AfricellNetFragment.java:117)
at com.esqmo.apps.mosungiplus.dialogs.MainDialog$3.onClick(MainDialog.java:215)
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:174)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Here is the fragment class:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import com.esqmo.apps.mosungiplus.R;
import com.esqmo.apps.mosungiplus.dialogs.MainDialog;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AfricellCBFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, MainDialog.OnItemSelectedListener {

    String cbCode = "1000";
    String hash = Uri.encode("#");

    private LinearLayout africellCbInt;
    private TextView africellCbDialogMsg;
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_africell_cb, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        africellCbInt = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.africell_cb_int);
        view.findViewById(R.id.button_africell_cb_1).setOnClickListener(this);
        view.findViewById(R.id.button_africell_cb_2).setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_africell_cb_1:
                String ussdCode = "*" + cbCode + Uri.encode("#");
                startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:" + ussdCode)));
                break;

            //TODO
            case R.id.button_africell_cb_2:

                ArrayList<MainDialog.Item> pickerItems = new ArrayList<>();
                pickerItems.add(new MainDialog.Item("Forfait gratuit", "0"));
                pickerItems.add(new MainDialog.Item("Forfait Africell - Africell", "1"));
                pickerItems.add(new MainDialog.Item("Forfait International et International 500", "2"));
                pickerItems.add(new MainDialog.Item("Solde bonus", "3"));
                pickerItems.add(new MainDialog.Item("Forfait Internet", "4"));
                pickerItems.add(new MainDialog.Item("Forfait Internet nuit", "5"));


                MainDialog dialog = MainDialog.newInstance(getActivity().getString(R.string.dialog_cb_title),
                        pickerItems, -1);

                dialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "ItemPicker");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(MainDialog fragment, MainDialog.Item item, int index) {
        if(index == 0){
            String ussdCode = "*1000*1" + hash;
            startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:" + ussdCode)));
        } else
        if(index == 1){
            String ussdCode = "*1000*2" + hash;
            startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:" + ussdCode)));
        } else
        if(index == 2){
            String ussdCode = "*1000*3" + hash;
            startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:" + ussdCode)));
        } else
        if(index == 3){
            String ussdCode = "*1000*4" + hash;
            startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:" + ussdCode)));
        } else
            if(index == 4){
                String ussdCode = "*1050*225" + hash;
                startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:" + ussdCode)));
            }
            else
                if(index == 5){
                    String ussdCode = "*1050*445" + hash;
                    startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:" + ussdCode)));
                }
    }
}
```

And the AlertDialog :

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import com.esqmo.apps.mosungiplus.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Dialog fragment that allows user to select an item from a list
 */
public class MainDialog extends DialogFragment {
    public static final String LOGTAG = "esQmo.MainDialog";

    /**
     * An item that can be displayed and selected by the MainDialog
     */
    public static class Item {
        private String title;
        private int intValue;
        private String stringValue;

        private static final String KEY_TITLE        = "title";
        private static final String KEY_INT_VALUE    = "intValue";
        private static final String KEY_STRING_VALUE = "stringValue";

        /**
         * Construct with title and integer value
         *
         * @param title Name displayed in list
         * @param value Integer value associated with item
         */
       /* public Item(String title, int value) {
            assert(!TextUtils.isEmpty(title));

            this.title = title;
            this.intValue = value;
        } */

        /**
         * Construct with title and string value
         *
         * @param title Name displayed in list
         * @param value String value associated with item
         */
        public Item(String title, String value) {
            assert(!TextUtils.isEmpty(title));

            this.title = title;
            this.stringValue = value;
        }

        /**
         * Construct from a bundle of values
         * @param bundle
         */
        public Item(Bundle bundle) {
            title = bundle.getString(KEY_TITLE, null);
            intValue = bundle.getInt(KEY_INT_VALUE, 0);
            stringValue = bundle.getString(KEY_STRING_VALUE, null);
        }

        /**
         * Get a Bundle of values that can be passed to the Item(Bundle) constructor
         * to re-create the object
         *
         * @return Bundle
         */
        public Bundle getValuesBundle() {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            bundle.putString(KEY_TITLE, title);
            bundle.putInt(KEY_INT_VALUE, intValue);
            if (stringValue != null) {
                bundle.putString(KEY_STRING_VALUE, stringValue);
            }

            return bundle;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public int getIntValue() {
            return intValue;
        }

        public String getStringValue() {
            return stringValue;
        }

        /**
         * Given a list of items, create a Bundle that can be passed to
         * Item.itemsFromBundle() to recreate them.
         *
         * @param items list of items
         * @return Bundle
         */
        public static Bundle bundleOfItems(List<Item> items) {
            int itemCount = items.size();
            ArrayList<Bundle> itemBundles = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; ++i) {
                itemBundles.add(items.get(i).getValuesBundle());
            }

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelableArrayList(ARG_ITEMS, itemBundles);
            return bundle;
        }

        /**
         * Given a Bundle created by Item.bundleOfItems(), recreate the
         * original list of items.
         *
         * @param bundle Bundle created by Item.bundleOfItems()
         * @return ArrayList&lt;Item&gt;
         */
        public static ArrayList<Item> itemsFromBundle(Bundle bundle) {
            ArrayList<Bundle> itemBundles = bundle.getParcelableArrayList(ARG_ITEMS);
            ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Bundle itemBundle: itemBundles) {
                items.add(new Item(itemBundle));
            }
            return items;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Interface for notification of item selection
     *
     * If the owning Activity implements this interface, then the fragment will
     * invoke its onItemSelected() method when the user clicks the OK button.
     */
    public interface OnItemSelectedListener {
        void onItemSelected(MainDialog fragment, Item item, int index);
    }

    private static final String ARG_TITLE = "ARG_TITLE";
    private static final String ARG_ITEMS = "ARG_ITEMS";
    private static final String ARG_SELECTED_INDEX = "ARG_SELECTED_INDEX";

    /**
     * Create a new instance of MainDialog with specified arguments
     *
     * @param title Dialog title text
     * @param items Selectable items
     * @param selectedIndex initial selection index, or -1 if no item should be pre-selected
     * @return MainDialog
     */
    public static MainDialog newInstance(String title, ArrayList<Item> items, int selectedIndex) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_TITLE, title);
        args.putBundle(ARG_ITEMS, Item.bundleOfItems(items));
        args.putInt(ARG_SELECTED_INDEX, selectedIndex);

        MainDialog fragment = new MainDialog();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    private String title;
    private ArrayList<Item> items;
    private int selectedIndex;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public MainDialog() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putInt(ARG_SELECTED_INDEX, selectedIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
            title = args.getString(ARG_TITLE, "Dialog");
            items = Item.itemsFromBundle(args.getBundle(ARG_ITEMS));
            selectedIndex = args.getInt(ARG_SELECTED_INDEX, -1);
        }

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            selectedIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_SELECTED_INDEX, selectedIndex);
        }

        String[] itemTitles = getItemTitlesArray();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.homepage_landing_icon).
                setTitle(title)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Log.d(LOGTAG, "OK button clicked");

                        Fragment fragment = getParentFragment();
                        if (fragment instanceof OnItemSelectedListener) {
                            if (0 <= selectedIndex && selectedIndex < items.size()) {
                                Item item = items.get(selectedIndex);
                                OnItemSelectedListener listener = (OnItemSelectedListener) fragment;
                                listener.onItemSelected(MainDialog.this, item, selectedIndex);

                        }
                        }
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Log.d(LOGTAG, "Cancel button clicked");

                        // OK, just let the dialog be closed
                    }
                })
                .setSingleChoiceItems(itemTitles, selectedIndex, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Log.d(LOGTAG, "User clicked item with index " + which);
                        selectedIndex = which;
                    }
                });

        return builder.create();
    }

    private String[] getItemTitlesArray() {
        final int itemCount = items.size();
        String[] itemTitles = new String[itemCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; ++i) {
            itemTitles[i] = items.get(i).getTitle();
        }
        return itemTitles;
    }
```

The error points here for the fragment:

```
startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel :" + ussdCode)));
```

and for the AlertDialog:

```
listener.onItemSelected(MainDialog.this, item, selectedIndex);
```

Anyone can help troubleshoot this? Because sometimes it works but randomly. What does the line

> No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL
>   dat=tel :*1050*100# } from the log?

Comment: To down voters: Instead of just down voting on people questions, please also mention the reason behind it! How for hell one will improve they question if you don't tell em what's​ wrong with that?!?

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Did you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />` permission to Manifest?

**2.** Change code to

```
Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData (Uri.parse ("tel:" + phoneNumber));
context.startActivity (intent);
```

**3.** YOu can use ACTION_DIAL to show dialer with provided number

Comment: Thanks for replying, but It doesn't work. context can't be resolved and even without​ the context, the app's still crashing.... I'm missing something I know that, but can't figure out, poor noob

Answer (score 1):

Use it to call-

```
String ussdCode = "*1000*2" + hash;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +ussdCode));
startActivity(intent);
```

Dont forget to add permission on Manifest.xml -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but the problem remains.